# Value of whisker in boxplot for 99.7 coverage

Tags: matlab, statistics, boxplot, normal-distribution, outliers

I am trying to identify outliers from a boxplot using MATLAB. The function has a default whisker value of 1.5 that provides +- 2.7*sigma or 99.3 coverage. 
However, I want 99.7 or 3*sigma coverage. What could be the value of whisker in this case?
I did not want to make a random guess, so need help from you guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, let:

```
Q1 = icdf('norm',0.25,0,1);
Q3 = icdf('norm',0.75,0,1);
IQR = Q3-Q1;
```

- Now if you have a constant `k` ([BOXPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/boxplot.html#zmw57dd0e47168) by default has `k=1.5` for the whisker length), then the [IQR outlier test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers) identifies values outside the range: `[Q1 - k*IQR, Q3 + k*IQR]` as outliers, which corresponds to:

  ```
  >> k = 1.5;
  >> sdCov = [Q1 - k*IQR, Q3 + k*IQR]      %# +/-2.698*sigma coverage
  sdCov =
         -2.698        2.698
  ```

  or (in terms of area under the curve):

  ```
  >> area = 2*normcdf(sdCov(2), 0, 1)-1    %# 99.3% coverage
  area =
         0.99302
  ```
- In the opposite direction, if you want a `sdCov*sigma` coverage, then:

  ```
  >> sdCov = 3;
  >> k = (Q1+sdCov)/IQR
  k =
         1.7239
  ```

  or:

  ```
  >> area = 0.9973;
  >> sdCov = norminv(1-(1-area)/2);
  >> k = (Q1+sdCov)/IQR
  ```

  Therefore use the following in your case:

  ```
  boxplot(data, 'whisker',1.7239)
  ```

Here is an illustration borrowed from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg):

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range]